# writing a formula for cell formatting in Excel for large dataset: turn outliers red

Tags: excel, excel-formula, outliers, cell-formatting

I have a large dataset (2209 rows x 60 columns) (each column is a compound i.e., ozone, ethane, etc.) of compound concentrations and I have a specific method for calculating outliers. Basically, I have calculated a number for each of the 50 compounds and any concentration that is greater than this number I calculated (located at the bottom of each compound column) is considered an outlier and I want to identify them by making their font red. I know this can be done in cell formatting but then I would have to do this for each individual column which is time consuming. I also have non-numeric symbols in my dataset to represent missing data ("x" and "--------") and I want to ignore those when finding outliers. I don't know much about writing macros (I usually do my data analysis in RStudio but I need the final product to be this Excel sheet with the outliers in red) but is there an easy way to format all the cells in each column ignoring those symbols and doing it for all the columns at once? Below is a screenshot example of the data I'm working with. [image]

Comment: There is something called "Conditional Formatting". It would be good, if you would provide some sample data, to see exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this, yes. You need to decide what an outlier is, for this formula I will assume anything greater than 2.0.

1) Select where you want this rule to apply, it looks like for you that would be all of rows 1 - 14.

2) Open "conditional formatting" and select "new rule"

3) "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

4) Use this formula `=AND(A$14>2,NOT(ISTEXT(A$14)))`

5) Click format and choose your preferred display

6) Click apply

For the formula, if you want to allow for negatives to also be counted then use `=AND(OR(A$14>2,A$14<-2),NOT(ISTEXT(A$14)))`. The row can be changed if the part you're measuring isn't on row 14 (ex. if it's on row 99 just use `=A$99>2`)